# ConTeXt: Sorting of entries in registers

Tags: context, indexing

**Background**

To influence the order in which ConTeXt puts register entries you can use a specific key value in

`\index[KEY]{Term}`

This is for instance useful if you want to mix upper-case and lower-case entries in your register, e.g.

```
\defineregister[regname]
\setupregister[regname]
   [compress=yes,
    indicator=no,
    pagestyle=\tf,
    n=1,
    before=\blank]

 \starttext
 \page
 % mixed
 Aa\regname[AA]{Aa}
 ab\regname[AB]{ab}
 Ac\regname[AC]{Ac}
 % not mixed
 Ba\regname[Ba]{Ba}
 bb\regname[bb]{bb}
 Bc\regname[Bc]{Bc}

 \page
 \placeregname
 \stoptext
```

leads to

[image: Register]

---

**Problem**

Sometimes there are words that only differ in the first letter (upper-case vs. lower-case). When both appear in the register and are mentioned on different pages, the register entries do not collapse, since the terms themselves start with different letters. E.g.

```
\defineregister[regname]
\setupregister[regname]
  [compress=yes,
   indicator=no,
   pagestyle=\tf,
   n=1,
   before=\blank]

 \starttext

 hebräisch\regname[HEBRÄISCH]{hebräisch}
 Hebräisch\regname[HEBRÄISCH]{Hebräisch}

 \page

 hebräisch\regname[HEBRÄISCH]{hebräisch}
 Hilfe\regname[HILFE]{Hilfe}

 \page

 \placeregname

 \stoptext
```

results in

[image: Register2]

---

**Question:**

Is it possible to sum up the entries with the same first letter without putting all lower-case entries behind all upper-case ones? I want to achieve something like this:

[image: Register3]

Comment: You are abusing `\index[key]{entry}`.  Specifying the `key` is reserved for cases where sorting cannot be deduced from `entry`, i.e. `\index[CONTEXT]{\ConTeXt}`.  Also the mapping `key <-> entry` has to be bijective, i.e. a single `key` has to map to a single `entry` and a single `entry` has to map to a single `key`.  Multimaps are not supported and there is no reason to support them either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the optional argument.  The optional argument is meant for cases where the sorting cannot be inferred from the content, i.e. `\regname[CONTEXT]{\ConTeXt}`.  This is clearly not the case for the words you use.  Adding this optional argument and having differing entries exempts the word from taking part in the collapse which leads to the behaviour you observe.  Instead of trying to trick ConTeXt into thinking that everything is uppercase, just tell it that you want to have uppercase words before lowercase in the index by adjusting the sorting method.

```
\defineregister[regname]
\setupregister[regname]
  [compress=yes,
   indicator=no,
   pagestyle=\tf,
   n=1,
   before=\blank,
   method={zc,mm,uc}]

\starttext

hebräisch\regname{hebräisch}
Hebräisch\regname{Hebräisch}
helfen\regname{helfen}
Herrscher\regname{Herrscher}
hölzern\regname{hölzern}

\page

hebräisch\regname{hebräisch}
Hilfe\regname{Hilfe}
haben\regname{haben}
Holz\regname{Holz}

\page

\placeregname

\stoptext
```

[image]

---

If you insist on using the optional argument, you have to use different keys for different entries.

```
\defineregister[regname]
\setupregister[regname]
  [compress=yes,
   indicator=no,
   pagestyle=\tf,
   n=1,
   before=\blank]

\starttext

hebräisch\regname[Hebräisch]{hebräisch}
Hebräisch\regname[HEBRÄISCH]{Hebräisch}

\page

hebräisch\regname[Hebräisch]{hebräisch}
Hilfe\regname[HILFE]{Hilfe}

\page

\placeregname

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the first solution you proposed and it works like charm. Thanks a lot!